# Free E-books for students on Volatility Models

Tags: research, books

Some e-books are free for students when they are on the university IP.

So can anyone provide a list of free e-books for students and free e-books in general about **(stochastic) volatility modelling?**

Answer (score 2):

There's no free lunch ! However, the best book (in my opinion) is "Stochastic Volatility Modeling" by Lorenzo Bergomi. On his web site, you can download free chapter and pdf from his presentations :

1. for free chapterhttps://www.lorenzobergomi.com/contents-sample-chapters
2. for papers : https://www.lorenzobergomi.com/papers

Comment: Howerve, depending on your university, some universities provide free pdf download for Wiley Finance collection. Good books on volatility are Option Pricing Models and Volatility Using Excel-VBA, The Volatility Smile, Volatility Modeling and Trading and Volatility Master Class for Quants